# How do I set up ssh keys in Google Compute Engine?

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine, putty

I am trying to set up ssh keys through the Google Cloud Platform console.
I made a key in Puttygen, 
but what is the format to paste it into the console?
I got this error:

```
Error: Invalid key. Required format: <protocol> <key-blob> <username@example.com>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

- After opening puttygen, select SSH-2 RSA and change the number of bits to 2048
- Click on generate and follow the instructions
- In the Key Comment textbox, put your email address
- Fill in the passphrase boxes too for good practice
- Save your private key somewhere
- Copy all of the text from the top, greyed-out textbox

You should end up with the following in the google ssh keys textbox

> ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQB5h1cM5uLB+1C7Al+RNuKoFz81P4mw89pYPDuARzZTNFPguHsfUNZ6Xtq2LF/CDoRh9G3Y9xt12H5TWdeZdmdaokwbtQYba86Ve7w0eLEw0Bwy4eQCC/hsVzNY37pUbdGBMbhOoYfJQ1gnz+4kZBtgNlk3PQiyWkBzBcIt6qHgd/ax8mS8Ty+0/cD1X50yEzyr/anP/WowZYIDb5rtM/+Rb/qZ6wZl1ka+AulT+9cH59ChHLDzeZc6NdJYhmS6K5DDebRaRWdviOiI+RpSMZz0hsHaGnQdpfrzswIwPolrA+nKQ24WZDPgWAzCAlvuLRdYB3dGDkLCnypAfHzwGyTj your@email.com

Then open putty, fill in the Session details and then go to Connection -> SSH -> Auth and click browse under Private key file for authentication.

After clicking open, your login name is the user part of your email address (before the @).  It will ask you for your passphrase too.

Comment: Unlike Google Official procedure - yours works correctly. 
This does not work with puttygen: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#generatesshkeypair

Comment: What about if PuTTY Key Gen does not have the SSH-2 option? ( only RSA, DSA ECDSA, ED25519 and SSH-1 )

Comment: Looks like 'RSA' is actually the same as SSH-2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42651825/puttygen-doesnt-give-me-the-option-for-ssh-2-rsa

Answer (score 3):

In GCE, `$gcloud` compute ssh  direct to `/.ssh/google_compute_engine`
so you might want to replace default gce file to the generated ssh file. You may also use a symlink to your actual key locations if you prefer.